# Bracket Matching - Find closing bracket with input bracket index - ValueError

Tags: python

newb here looking for help with my bracket code. I want to find the index of the closing bracket
from a open/close bracket string given a starting index

```
def matching_bracket(string, idx):
    string = list(string)
    a = {
        "(": ")",
        "[": "]",
        "{": "}",
        "<": ">"
    }
    close_bracket = a[string[idx]]
    if idx != ''.join(string).rindex(string[idx]):      #if open bracket is first bracket
        b = ''.join(string).rindex(string[idx])         #rightmost open bracket
        c = string[b:].index(close_bracket)             #next closest close bracket
        string[b], string[b+c:] = ".", "."              #replace both
        string = matching_bracket(''.join(string), idx)  # recurse
    else:
        d = string[idx:].index(close_bracket)
        return(idx + d)

matching_bracket("(([()]))",0)          #this fails, get error "ValueError: ')' is not in list"

matching_bracket('({})', 0) == 3             #yet these few output a correct val???
matching_bracket('([])', 1) == 2
matching_bracket('()()', 2) == 3
```

can anyone help me???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of an odd way to do this (I would usually do things like this with a stack). But I can see a few issues, including the one that causes the value error.

The first is that `string[b+c:]` replaces everything from index `b+c` onward, you really wanted `string[b+c]`. So on the first run `"(([()]))"` becomes `"(([.."`, which is not what you want.

The second is that you're not returning the value returned by your recursive step. I updated here those.

```
def matching_bracket(string, idx):
    a = {
        "(": ")",
        "[": "]",
        "{": "}",
        "<": ">"
    }
    close_bracket = a[string[idx]]

    if idx != string.rindex(string[idx]):      #if open bracket is first bracket
        b = string.rindex(string[idx])         #rightmost open bracket
        c = string[b:].index(close_bracket)             #next closest close bracket
        str_list = list(string)
        str_list[b], str_list[b+c] = ".", "."              #replace both
        return matching_bracket(''.join(str_list), idx)  # recurse
    else:
        d = string[idx:].index(close_bracket)
        return idx + d
```

Hopefully that clears things up for you.

Comment: Oh wow!!! tks! this solved the issue completely! Btw if you don't mind me asking where can I learn about this stack that you mention?

Comment: Glad I could help! So a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) is a data structure that's useful in the [bracket matching](https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/pythonds/BasicDS/SimpleBalancedParentheses.html) problem. You could do a slightly modified version where you push the start idx bracket onto an empty stack, then iterate through the string pushing/popping brackets. When the stack is empty, it means you've found your match. If you get to the end of the string, there is no matching close. Could be interesting to think about for you. Good luck!